# HTML5 Phone App - Rescaling for Retinas

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

This is my first time developing html5 for a mobile device. I'm wanting my app to run universal, so it needs to take into account retina displays as well as normal ones.

I'm running this code, and it seems to look fine on both iPhone3G (normal display), and iPhone5 (retina display):

```
function Setup(){

    $('canvas').css('width', window.innerWidth + 'px');
    $('canvas').css('height', window.innerHeight + 'px');

    if(window.devicePixelRatio == 2) {
        canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth * 2);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight * 2);
        ctx.scale(2, 2);
    }
    else{
        canvas.setAttribute('width', window.innerWidth);
        canvas.setAttribute('height', window.innerHeight);
        ctx.scale(1, 1);
    }

    Draw();

}
```

I really just want to know if I'm going about this the correct way? Everything looks fine, but I don't want to find out later, after days of work and coding, that this is a wrong/bad way to do it.

Also, I understand that I need 2 versions of an image, eg: a 32x32 image for a normal screen, and a 64x64 for a retina, but I need to scale that image down by 50%. Correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctx.scale` will probably work, but will probably make your images look like shit ie. streched.

Of course you could use the retina sized images and scale down, but then your putting an extra workload on non-retina devices - like the 3gs - which is already slooow.

The method I use is this:

```
myCanvas.width = 300;
myCanvas.height = 300;

// you can use variables to get this value: width * window.devicePixelRatio
myCanvas.style.width = "600px";
myCanvas.style.height = "600px";
```

Of course you would also need to scale all your inputs by window.devicePixelRatio!